# How to get when nodetool snapshot is finished on cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am writing python script creating and uploading Cassandra backups to external storage. Cassandra cluster is presented by three nodes and every node has two JBOD disks.

The script starts *nodetool snapshot* command and this command starts snapshot creation job on cluster and exits immediately while snapshot creation process continues its operation. Now script should wait until snapshot creation will be finished and continue with upload. Question is how to get snapshot creation status?

Answer (score 1):

`nodetool snapshot` creates hard links to the sstables. When  the command exits, the snapshot is complete. it's typically v. fast

Comment: In my case there is more than 700 tables in keyspace and because of that it is not fast.